# how to call toolStripProgressBar.PerformStep() from another class

Tags: c#

i have a toolStripProgressBar created in class A
and i want to perform the next steps depending on class B by (PerformStep() method)

Answer (score 0):

Raise an event from class B that class A will react too.

Comment: Or add a reference to class A from class B and create a function to do a step. But the Event model is more flexible for the future.